# How to javascript validate <input type=file multiple> if browser does not support multiple

Tags: javascript, file, validation, input

I'm using:

```
<input type='file' name='pac1[]' multiple>
```

How do I javascript validate that there is at least one file selected?

When using:

```
<input type='file' name='pac1'>
```

I have no problem validating a single non-array entry.

Comment: `this.files.length` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
<input id="upload" type='file' name='pac1[]' multiple>
```

And JS:

```
if(document.getElementById("upload").files.length < 1)
{
   alert("No file selected");
   return false;
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you.

Comment: Found an issue. What if the browser (like IE8) does not support multiple? The script then fails on that length check.

Comment: Is there a solution other than checking to see if browser supports it?

Answer (score 0):

Bind `change` event on `input type='file'` element using `addEventListener`

`INPUTElement.files.length` will return number of files selected.

```js
document.querySelector('[name="pac1[]"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
  alert(this.files.length);
});
```

```html
<input type='file' name='pac1[]' multiple>
```

Comment: The change event won't fire if there is no file selected :-) ("*validate that there is **at least one** file selected*")

Comment: @Kaiido, True! :P I did not consider the term _"validation"_ :(